# Unable to call a method inside another method in the same class using python

Tags: python

i switched to python after some few months of learning c#. am a newbie in both.
i was getting an "undefined variable 'appender' error msg and for other def method in the class. i removed it from the class and noticed that the password list is always empty and never updates. how can i fix this?
feel free to check the code and criticize it, am still learning and don't know how this fully works
THANKS

```
import random
#Lists of avaliable code options
numb_opt = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
char_opt = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
sym_opt = ['~','!','#','@','$','%','?','/']
avaliable_code = [numb_opt, char_opt, sym_opt]

""" This class generates and returns password based on data passed by the user. """
class generator:

    def __init__(self, passLength, charLength, symLength, numbLength):
        #initializing attributes
        self.passLength = passLength
        self.charLength = charLength
        self.symLength = symLength
        self.numbLength = numbLength

    #Passcode generator
    #select random list and passcode from list and append to empty list
    def passcode_generator(self):
            counter = 1
            while counter <= self.passLength:
                active_list = random.choice(avaliable_code)     #pick random list from lists
                #check which list by index, generated code of len == user's, append code and remove list
                if active_list == avaliable_code[0] and isList_used(active_list) == False:
                    c = 1
                    while c <= self.numbLength:
                        p = random.choice(active_list)
                        appender(p)
                        c += c
                    pass
                elif active_list == avaliable_code[1] and isList_used(active_list) == False:
                    c = 1
                    while c <= self.charLength:
                        p = random.choice(active_list)
                        appender(p)
                        c += c
                    pass
                elif active_list == avaliable_code[2] and isList_used(active_list) == False:
                    c = 1
                    while c <= self.symLength:
                        p = random.choice(active_list)
                        appender(p)
                        c += c
                    pass
                counter += counter
                pass
'''
#Passcode appender
def appender(code):
    passwords = []      #empty list which would hold passwords durig generation.
    passwords.append(code)
    print(passwords) '''

#Exiting dialog
def exiting_dialog(self):
    print("Closing session...........")
    print("Exiting program")
    pass

def PrintOut(passwrd):
    return passwrd

#Returns true if list is used
def isList_used(u_list):
    isUsed = False
    used = []
    #check if active list is in used list. if yes, don't use list
    if u_list in used:
        isUsed = True       #if list is used
    elif u_list not in used:
        isUsed = False      #if list is not used
        used.append(u_list)
    return isUsed
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation? Or confirm that this is the indentation you have? Also, can you include an example of how you're calling your script and the full traceback that occurs when you do?

Comment: yes this is the indentation. i created a new script call 'test' i imported the the generator class from the script {from script_name import generator.